# Extracting a number of specific length from a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string like

```
ADN120_XK7760069988881LJ
```

in one of my columns. I have to extract the number with 13 digits length. For example, in the above case, I want to extract `7760069988881` in SQL Server.

Comment: Is is always starting in the exact same location in your string or can it fall anywhere in there?

Comment: Hi Sean , It can start from anywhere, not the same location , but i have to extract 13 digit code every time regardless of the location.

Answer (score 7):

using [**`patindex()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql) with [**`substring()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql) (using a variable for the pattern and [**`replicate()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replicate-transact-sql) to simplify repeating `[0-9]` 13 times):

```
create table t (val varchar(128));
insert into t values ('ADN120_XK7760069988881LJ');

declare @pattern varchar(128) = '%'+replicate('[0-9]',13)+'%';

select substring(val,patindex(@pattern,val),13)
from t;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/MOEVG64754

returns `7760069988881`

Comment: While this does work on the given sample data, it fails if the string is like `ADN120_XK17760069988881LJ7760069988881`.   It returns the first 13 characters of the 14-digit number, instead of the 13-digit number.   Nifty trick though.

Comment: @TabAlleman If that is an issue, change `+'%'` to `+ '[^0-9]%'` to the end of the `replicate()`

Comment: That's what I was thinking.  But you'd actually have to change the '%' on both sides wouldn't you?   Otherwise you get the last 13 digits of the 14-digit number.

Comment: @TabAlleman Ya, you're right that isn't going to work. If 14 digit numbers are an issue, need more info in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Creating TEMP table with your query

```
SELECT 'ADN120_XK7760069988881LJ' CODE INTO #TEMP
```

Solution using regular expression

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CODE,PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',CODE),13)
FROM #TEMP
```

Couldn't reduce the number of times [0-9] used

Hope this helps